# Planning together multiple sequential motions in Moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use Moveit and a Baxter robot to perform some complex actions (i.e. each action is composed of multiple motions) on a table.

My main issue is that sometimes these action would fail simply because one of these motions left the robot arms in some configuration that does not leave enough space for the successive motions to be planned successfully. This happens especially when the objects on the table I'm acting upon are very close to each other.

Is there a way in Moveit to plan multiple sequential goals together before actually moving the arms? Alternatively, can you suggest any other strategy to avoid these kind of conflicts?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274209/planning-together-multiple-sequential-motions-in-moveit/) by [alessiocpt](https://answers.ros.org/users/23182/alessiocpt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way in Moveit to plan multiple sequential goals together before actually moving the arms?

Yes: in the [move group interface](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html), you can use the [plan](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#ad72e3d9367374e388546c8e81f26035a) method to get the path that will be executed, without actually executing it yet. You can then plan the next path by setting the start to be the goal state of the previous motion with [setStartState](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#af633a8772b33720ec482490a592fafcc).

> Alternatively, can you suggest any other strategy to avoid these kind of conflicts?

You've essentially described the problem of Task and Motion Planning. There [exist](http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/rss12/p02.pdf) [plenty](http://people.csail.mit.edu/lpk/papers/hpn2.pdf) of [papers](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Erussell/papers/icra14-planrob.pdf) on the topic, but from my knowledge, there aren't any widely used ROS frameworks for this problem. If anyone knows of some, please mention them!

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2